Error: Missing Type HttpServletRequest in Maven Project for File Upload
Question:
I am working on a Maven project for a file upload servlet and encountered an issue. When I try to parse the request using ServletFileUpload, I get the following error:

The method parseRequest(HttpServletRequest) from the type ServletFileUpload refers to the missing type HttpServletRequest

Here is my FileUpload servlet code:
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@MultipartConfig
public class FileUpload extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            ServletFileUpload sf = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory());
            List<FileItem> multifiles = sf.parseRequest(request);
            
            for (FileItem item : multifiles) {
                item.write(new File("C:\\FileUploadDemo" + item.getName()));
            }
            System.out.println("File Uploaded");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}

I have the following dependencies in my pom.xml:
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

Could anyone help me resolve this error? What might be causing the HttpServletRequest type to be missing, and how can I fix it?

Additional Information:

I am using Eclipse for my development environment.
The @MultipartConfig annotation is being used to handle file uploads.

Thanks in advance!

SQL Server <> MySQL; which are you really using?

If you are using "The @MultipartConfig annotation is being used to handle file uploads." Then why did you add a commons-fileupload library if you can handle upload with the answer to Servlet receives null values after uploading a file.

Apache Commons file upload versions 1.4 and 1.5 both have a provided dependency on the servlet API spec for a version that still uses javax in its package names. It doesn't work with the jakarta package prefix. In other words, you won't be able to use version 1.x in combination with jakarta.
They are working on version 2 but it's not final yet.
